# Jquery get current year for event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a site that has has many events and days/holidays, they have a function that happens when countdown to that date completes, all similar to this  ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#TheEvents").countdown({
date: "july 04, 2014 12:00",
"onComplete" : function(event) { 
$(".ThisEvent").slideUp("slow");  
}           
});
});
```

Since they all have a set date every year my question is - is there a way to put the current year were '2014' is like {TheCurrentYear} ?

I really dont want to have to go and change to 2015 etc. to restart countdown after every event completes :-)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `var year = new Date().getFullYear()` [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate the year dynamically by creating a new Date object, and then calling **getFullYear()**:

```
$("#TheEvents").countdown({
    date: "july 04, " + new Date().getFullYear() + " 12:00",
    onComplete : function(event) { 
        $(".ThisEvent").slideUp("slow");  
    }           
});
```

Comment: I really thought this was going to work, it must be close :) , it made my timer disappear all together..

Comment: @Frosty I was missing a space. Try the updated code.